# Getting the selected value's ID from a dropdown menu in ASP.NET Core

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, drop-down-menu

```
    @model List<CompanyListVM>
    @{
        Layout = "_AdminLayout";
    }
    <form asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="List" id="formAccountSettings" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="container">
            <select name="CompanyId" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Şirket Seçiniz</option>
                @foreach (var company in Model)
                {
                    <option value="@company.CompanyId">@company.CompanyName</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #AAC8A7;"> Yöneticileri Listele </button> 
        </div>
    </form>




 

   [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> List()
    {
        var currentUserId = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        var responseTask = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"/company");
        if (responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var json = await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var companies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootModelCompany>(json).data;
            return View(companies);
        }

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> List(CompanyListVM companyListVM,int pageStartWith=1)
    {
        int id = companyListVM.CompanyId;
        var responseTask = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"/com/{id}");
        if(responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var json = await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootModelCompanyManager>(json).data;
            return View(users.ToPagedList(pageStartWith, 10));
        }

        return View();
    }



      public class CompanyListVM
      {
          public int CompanyId { get; set; }
          public string CompanyName { get; set; }       
      }
    
      public class RootModelCompany
      {
          public List<object> errors { get; set; }
          public bool hasError { get; set; }
          public List<CompanyListVM> data { get; set; }
      }
```

Hello. First of all, I apologize for my bad English. I am a junior developer. I want to list the managers of the company selected from the dropdown menu using the company's Id. However, the companyId is coming as 0 in the post method, and also CompanyName is appearing as null. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `asp-items`:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> List()
    {
        var currentUserId = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        var responseTask = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"/company");
        if (responseTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var json = await responseTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var companies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootModelCompany>(json).data;
            //add below line
            ViewBag.companies = new SelectList(companies, "CompanyId", "CompanyName");
            return View(companies);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<select name="CompanyId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.companies">
        <option value="">Şirket Seçiniz</option>
        
    </select>
```

HttpPost  method:

```
 [HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> List(int CompanyId,  CompanyListVM companyListVM,int pageStartWith = 1)
 {    ...
   // get the CompanyName by the CompanyId
   var CompanyName = companies.Where(c => c.CompanyId == CompanyId)
                    .Select(c => c.CompanyName).FirstOrDefault();
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Dilara PINAR , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know? 
Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thank you very much.